# Python: Access a zipped XL file without extracting it

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles, zip

Is there a way I can process an open the excel file within a zip file without first extracting it.  I am not interested in modifying it.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from openpyxl import load_workbook

procFile ="C:\\Temp2\\XLFile-Demo-PW123.zip"
xl_file = "XLFile-Demo.xlsx"

myzip = ZipFile(procFile)
myzip.setpassword(bytes('123', 'utf-8'))

# line below returns an error
with load_workbook(myzip.open(xl_file)) as wb_obj:
    print(wb_obj.sheetnames)
```

Most of the examples that perform this only directly open text files.

I would like to simulate the behaviour of archiving programs such as WinRar and 7zip.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: @JohnS  with load_workbook(myzip.open(xl_file)) as wb_obj:  \n
AttributeError: __enter__ \n
python-BaseException \n
Process finished with exit code 1